# Determining global minimum structures for ion-water clusters

Tags: molecular-structure, density-functional-theory

What is the best way to find the global minimum structure(or get close to it) for an ion and N waters? (i.e. ion cluster in vacuum)

- For example, consider Flouride ion cluster with N=5 waters.
- I want to determine the global minimum structure (using Gaussian09 for a given level of theory and basis set).
- This helped me get started ([Geometry optimization: dependence on initial geometry](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/57116/geometry-optimization-dependence-on-initial-geometry)), but initial geometry sampling is easier for molecules compared to clusters.

  - What is an intelligent way to generate reasonable initial configurations for this cluster (say for N=4,5,6)?
  - Constraint: My computational resources allows me to optimize about 10 structures at a given time for a reasonable level of DFT theory. I might be able to do a maximum of 100-200 optimizations.

Comment: @AjayMurlidharan Welcome to the site! If haven't yet, visit the [help] and take the [tour]. Not my area of expertise, but my understanding is people usually obtain reasonable starting geometries by running Molecular dynamics simulations.

Comment: @Tyberius: Thanks! Also, I thought about this. I already have an ab-initio MD trajectory (~50 ps) of the ion in bulk water (Flouride ion and 64 waters with Periodic boundary conditions).  I could in principle sample cluster configurations from here. Trying to figure out if this is the best way with my computational resource limitations.

Comment: Finding a global minimum of (generalizing here) a many-dimensional function is a great problem in numerical methods. In my opinion, a good place to start reading is about [simulated annealing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simulated_annealing), which is commonly used in optimizing molecular configurations.